# Elements between panels are not aligned within a sizer

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have two panels to which I am both adding to a single sizer at the top level, however the elements within those panels are not aligned with each other.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        mygridsizer = wx.GridBagSizer()    

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self,label="Hello world"))
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label="hello"))
        mygridsizer.Add(sizer, pos=(0,0))
        mygridsizer.Add(wx.ComboBox(self), pos=(0,1))
        self.SetSizer(mygridsizer)

class MyPanel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel2, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label="non-aligned button"))
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(None)
        sizer = wx.GridSizer(3, 1)
        panel1 = MyPanel(parent=self)
        panel2 = MyPanel2(parent=self)
        sizer.Add(panel1)
        sizer.Add(panel2)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

With the example above, what can I do to align the buttons of both the panels?

Comment: Make all the widgets the same size? Provide a small runnable example along with OS, wxPython and Python versions and we may be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the sizer is aligning the Panels, if you want the buttons aligned you should make them part of the same sizer (not part of two Panels with their own sizers). You could also do something like this for a quick hack (essentially adding a spacer the same size as the text):

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        mygridsizer = wx.GridBagSizer()    

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self,label="Hello world"))
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label="hello"))
        mygridsizer.Add(sizer, pos=(0,0))
        mygridsizer.Add(wx.ComboBox(self), pos=(0,1))
        self.SetSizer(mygridsizer)

class MyPanel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel2, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        t = wx.StaticText(self,label="Hello world")
        t.Hide()
        t.GetSize()
        sizer.Add(t.GetSize())
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, label="non-aligned button"))
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(None)
        sizer = wx.GridSizer(3, 1)
        panel1 = MyPanel(parent=self)
        panel2 = MyPanel2(parent=self)
        sizer.Add(panel1)
        sizer.Add(panel2)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: so basically its not possible to achieve alignment without having to know the structure of the the sizer. As Mike Driscoll pointed out, it is possible to achieve vertical and horizontal alignment by making all the widgets the same size (row, column) in terms of the sizer by using the Spacer for non-existent elements, which you suggested.

Comment: p.s. the spacers would have to be the same size as the largest (width, height) elements being added or else the space would be too small/large.

Comment: Or use a different sizer arrangement, remember nesting BoxSizer is pretty much like adding a 1D array to a single location/cell/index of another 1D array... so maybe you can just re-think how you want things arrannged. For example you could think of your design using columns... you'd have a horizontal box with nested vertical boxes. Now you can add to the first column your 'Hello world' and a spacer just for placeholder below it (no specific size, just some), then the second column would have the two buttons. Or use the GridBagSizer which allows widgets to spill over into adjacent sizer cells.